# PostConfirmationTrigger for federated sign-in in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for auth. I am using AWS Amplify framework.

Currently I have email-password signup option. On Cognito `PostConfirmationTrigger` I add user to User DynamoDB table.
I want to add google signup option as well.

In federated sign-in (signup time), this trigger is not triggered so I am unable to add user to User DynamoDB table.

Any hints how can I invoke that trigger lambda only for first time federated sign-in (signup)?

Answer (score 0):

The post confirmation trigger is worth avoiding as it also doesn't trigger for admin confirmations. Reimplement it as a post-authentication or pre-token-generation trigger and, if need be, add a condition expression to your put item request to avoid overwriting existing user items.

Cognito is a bit borked when it comes to federated sign-on and triggers. Triggers only seem to be called the first time a user logs in.

Comment: what is difference between post-authentication & post-confirmation triggers? Can I  use post-confirmation for same purpose as latter one , also will it work same in case of email-password signups apart from federated signups ?

Comment: Actually I need a trigger only at signup & not subsequent signins/logins as I insert user row in DynamoDB after signup verification success